# How can I use the details given in the login page in some other pages of my website?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to use the user name entered in a sites login page to show, on the home page, `Welcome 'username'`. Also I want to use this information in other pages to check against data in a database. What will be the easiest way to do this?

So far, I have entered this in `login.php`

```
setcookie("user",$_POST['userid'],time()+3600);
```

Then in the home page I entered

```
echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["user"];
```

But I get an error

> Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\Arun\Internal_website\home.php

Comment: You may want to consider using cookies or sessions for this. (http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: @ShashankKadne: can u explain it briefly....

Comment: Hv a look here...http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is done by storing the username or some identifying information into a session, then save the session id into the cookie.  When the user goes to the next page, retrieve the session id from the cookie, then retrieve the session, then retrieve the username out of the session.

Also remember to sanitize any user input values before you display them using htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the cookie has been set. In Firefox You can see this under Tools > Page Info > Security > View Cookies

If it's not set check if the `$_POST['userid']` has been set:

```
echo $_POST['userid']
```

And by the way:

> The setcookie() function must appear BEFORE the `<html>` tag.

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)